# How to implement auto closing of double quotes, parentheses, brackets with prompt_toolkit used in iPython 7.x?

Tags: python, ipython, auto-close, prompt-toolkit

IPython since version 5 onward uses prompt_toolkit instead of readline, and I am trying to use its implementation of this package to enable auto closing of double quotes, parentheses and brackets. I have got as far as this code:

```
ip = get_ipython()
kb = ip.pt_app.key_bindings
@kb.add('"')
def _(event):
    buffer = event.current_buffer
    buffer.insert_text('"')
    buffer.insert_text('"')
```

This doesn't work correctly, as it merely inputs the two quotes, with the cursor positioned after them. The `buffer` object does not seem to have a method for moving the cursor back. There is a `document` object though, that the `buffer` contains, which has methods for inserting text before or after the cursor position. So amending the code:

```
ip = get_ipython()
kb = ip.pt_app.key_bindings
@kb.add('"') 
def _(event): 
    buffer = event.current_buffer 
    doc = buffer.document 
    doc.insert_before('"') 
    doc.insert_after('"')
```

This produces no output when '"' is pressed on the keyboard. I gather from the prompt_toolkit documentation, that the document should now be rendered to the screen, but I'm lost as to how to get this done. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to the immediate problem - my code was missing a parameter:

```
def _(event):
    buffer = event.current_buffer
    buffer.insert_text('"')
    buffer.insert_text('"', move_cursor=False)
```

A fuller answer regarding the rendering of the `document` object would still be appreciated, as that will be required for other related operations, such as deleting the matched quotes.